# How to set a loop to execute modules(*.py) from another packages?

Tags: python, loops, module, package

There are several modules under different packages, shown below:

```
proj
  tc_mgr_folder
     tcd.py
  package1/
     __init__.py
     subPack1/   
     __init__.py
     module_11.py
     module_12.py
         module_13.py
     subPack2/
        __init__.py
        module_21.py
        module_22.py
    ...
```

I would like to write a loop includes those modules(module_11, module_12, module_13, module_21, module_22,...) in **tcd.py** to test all once. Then save the output messages exported from each module to a text file. Can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the files in a directory using [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/glob.html#glob.glob).

You can then import each module using [`importlib.import_module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module):

```
for module in ['os', 'sys']:
    try:
        importlib.import_module(module)
    except ImportError:
        print("Could not import module: {}".format(module))
```